# Демон на сервер Linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю я демона на сервере Linux, через ps ax мне выводит статус S, то есть процесс остановлен, а через jobs -l говорит что процесс работает. Чему верить?

UPD: все работает, просто демон большую часть времени ждет и поэтому статус S

Comment: S - это ни разу не "остановлен". "Остановлен" — это T или t. Но нормальный демон в jobs не показывается. Читайте маны в сторону setsid()

Comment: а что это? ну приостановлен, суть то что не работает, как мне проверить работает ли он?

Comment: Если выполняет свои задачи, то работает, если нет - то нет, это же очевидно. Ну, strace ещё.

Comment: S — это значит процесс спит, ожидая какого-то события (например, получения данных из интернета). Как только событие произойдёт — процесс перейдёт в состояние R и обработает его, а потом обратно вернётся в S. Здесь всё нормально, всё работает как и должно.

Comment: А вообще демоны нужно запускать через штатную систему инициализации ОС, а не в jobs.